# Function that takes a start and end date and counts how many Sundays between those dates fell on the 1st of the month on kdb+

Tags: kdb

Creating a function that takes a start and end date and counts how many Sundays between those dates fell on the 1st of the month on kdb+, how would I do this?

The function needs to show how many times this has happened since 1950

Answer (score 1):

Let's define a function which returns a weekday of its argument (of type `date`) first.

The underlying value of a date is the count of days from 1/1/2000 and we know that 1/1/2000 was Saturday. The next day was obviously Sunday, then Monday etc. and every 7th, 14th, 21st, etc. day after and before Jan 1, 2000 was Saturday too. So if we take a date modulo 7 we'll get a weekday number where 0 is Saturday, 1 is Sunday, etc. which leads us to the following definition.

```
weekday:{ `sat`sun`mon`tue`wed`thu`fri x mod 7 }
```

Now we can create a function that answers the original question:

```
sundaysThe1st:{[start;end]sum `sun=weekday dates where 1=`dd$dates:start+til 1+end-start }
```

`start+til 1+end-start` generates a list of dates between `start` and `end`, `` dates where 1=`dd$dates `` returns only the first days of the months and `` `sun=weekday dates `` returns `1b` if the 1st day of the month is Sunday and `0b` otherwise. `sum` is effectively the number of 1's which is exactly what we need.

Hope this helps.